# Bash Script to remove iframe virus

Tags: bash, iframe, scripting, virus

I want a bash script to read all files recursively in a directory and remove some code (i.e a iframe virus) from it and save back the orignal file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to show that piece of iframe to remove, but generally you can do this with find & sed. If you don't know exactly how to write such script, give us more information like html files extensions and iframe pattern to remove (especially if it is not always the same).

OK, suppose you have PHP files and you want to remove every iframe tag (so, there are no other useful iframes), you can use this solution: first, write `change.sh` shell script like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sed 's/<iframe[^>]*>.*<\/iframe>//g' < "$1" > "$1.tmp"
mv "$1.tmp" "$1"
```

Then, you can use this:

```
find . -name "*.php" | xargs -i ./change.sh {} \;
```

And that will do the job. My tests passed.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3211-PHP-Search-files-and-replace-their-content.html you can use this class for it

Answer (score 0):

Would [this](http://www.nullamatix.com/find-r57-and-c99-shells-hidden-inside-php-and-txt-files/) be appropriate?